# How to create chart of stats grouped per month and per user doing them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that counts items acted on by certain users. The problem is that every day the sheet gets refreshed, *not* with the items done that day, but with the items done *up to* that day. For example:

```
Month     |Date      | User      | Items done
_____________________________________________
September |01-09-2017| Mike      | 10
September |02-09-2017| Mike      | 15
```

Meaning that on 01-09 the user had acted on 10 items, but on 02-09 he had acted on 15, meaning that from one day to another he just did 5, so the "Items done" is the cumulative amount.

[Here is a demo sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fYYaJBqx_ouPTOA-quLYYt-LO542LApTABZCmQoO4QE/edit?usp=sharing)

How can I plot a chart of

1. Total amount of items acted on by the sum of all users in each month
2. Progression of each individual user through the months

I tried to extract the values from a pivot table (you can see it on the demo) but I am finding a problem: In order to get the total value for a user, I need to use MAX instead of SUM, because of what I explained of cumulative amount.

But if I want the total done in one month by all the users, I need to do SUM, because now I really need to sum the values. But when building the pivot table, in "Values" I can select only one option, SUM or MAX. I cannot say "MAX for individual users and SUM for total monthly".

Do you have an idea about how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just use two pivot tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some variations of `QUERY` to achieve the visualization you desperately require:

```
=QUERY(A1:D197;"select B, Max(D) group by B pivot C")
```

This will provide the SUM:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:D197;"select B,C,  Max(D) group by B,  C");"select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1")
```

Syntax:

[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)